# Assigning the same value to all Pyspark column elements using WithColumn

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Here is my code :

```
for s, sub_direct in enumerate(os.listdir(path_csv1)):  
    for i, file in enumerate (glob.glob(path_csv1+"/"+sub_direct+"/*.csv")):
        df_spa = spark.read.csv(file,header=True,sep=",")
        df_spa = df_spa.withColumn("Batt_id", sub_direct)
        #df=df.append(df_spa)
        df = df.union(df_spa)
```

Based in the value of `sub_direct` I wil update my column `df_spa ['Batt_id']`

I got the next error and I could not understand how to solve it [image]

I know it expectes a column but here I need to assign the same string to all the values of the column with a folder

Is it possible? lit does not worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **`lit()`** while passing a variable

**`from pyspark.sql import functions as F`**

**`df_spa = df_spa.withColumn("Batt_id", F.lit(sub_direct))`**